# using pinvoke with structs and pointers

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I am trying to pinvoke a c function within my c# code.  It takes a struct and a double as an input and returns a struct of the same type.  I've defined the struct the same in the c and c# code.  when pinvoking the c function I get an exception "Methods type signature is not PInvoke compatible".  Can somebody spot what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks

C:

```
typedef struct myStruct_struct
{
     double prefix[8];
     int length;
     double array[1];
}
myStruct;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) myStruct *doSomething(const myStruct *inStruct, double val)
{
   myStruct *outStruct;
   //doSomething ...
   return outStruct;
}
```

C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct myStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public double[] Prefix;
    public int Length;
    public IntPtr ArrayPtr;

    public void MarshalArray(double[] array)
    {
        Length = array.Length;
        int pointerSize = IntPtr.Size + (8 * Length);
        ArrayPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(pointerSize));
        Marshal.Copy(array, 0, ArrayPtr, Length);
    }

    public double[] UnMarshalArray()
    {
        double[] array = new double[Length];
        Marshal.Copy(ArrayPtr, array, 0, Length);
        return array;
    }
}

[DllImport("testing.dll", EntryPoint = "doSomething", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IntPtr test_doSomething(IntPtr inStruct, double val); 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myStruct s = createStruct();
        myStruct result = MarshalIn(test_doSomething(MarshalOut(s), 2));
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
}

private myStruct MarshalIn(IntPtr intPtr)
{
    myStruct s = (myStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(intPtr, typeof(myStruct));

    s.UnMarshalArray();

    return s;
}

private IntPtr MarshalOut(myStruct s)
{
    double[] array = new double[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2 };
    s.MarshalArray(array);

    IntPtr outPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(myStruct)));

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(s, outPtr, true);

    return outPtr;
}
```

Comment: LPStruct and Struct are fickle creatures.  Usually the marshaller will come back with an error about that, but that didn't happen this time, but it possibly will if you get to that point, because that's not a ref or an out struct, it's just a struct (even if it's passed by pointer, I don't think it qualifies as an LPStruct.  

Your best bet is to probably add a true ref struct variable to the end of the parameters line to receive the output structure and simply return void or bool as the function's return value.)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to change the c code signature.  its used in other places.

Comment: [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)] is missing on the array declaration.  Remove UnmanagedType.LPStruct.  You must use *ref* on the argument to match myStruct* in the native code.  Manual marshaling with IntPtr is required if the function returns data in the array.

Comment: Then you will need to write a wrapper in C that is p/Invokable.

Comment: I just noticed that... it looks like an array placeholder for a variable-length array, if I'm not mistaken.  Variable length arrays must be marshalled manually.  It is not easy to marshal them.  I've actually got a solution to this problem in code if you want it, but given what I've said it should be enough for you to work out. The memory for the structure, it's getting allocated somewhere?

Comment: @Hans I have modified code as per your suggestion (above) but still getting same error.

Comment: There's more trouble, you can't return a struct like that.  Return value must be declared as IntPtr and marshaled with Marshal.PtrToStructure().  Also a very nasty memory management problem, the memory for that struct needs to be released.  All and all low odds to ever get this right, this function is just very unfriendly.  Use a C++/CLI wrapper instead.

Comment: @Nathan, may I have a peek at your solution?

Comment: Are you prepared to consider changes to your unmanaged code? If not then I guess you can struggle along with manual marshalling and exporting deallocators. If you are prepared to change then a simple solution is available.

Comment: Sure, I just posted one.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this might not be the best solution in the world, but it is working for me in my tests, so I will leave you to infer things that you may personally need to do with regard to memory releasing, and leave you to your own judgment regarding that.

I personally HATE using Marshal.Copy and Buffer.BlockCopy.  I wrote my own line of functions for this, here: http://nmcsmem.codeplex.com/  (Specifically the DTCSMemory project -> MemPtr structure), but I programmed this with the standard functions for easy portability.  I have to admit, I may be doing some funky things with the bytes there, but I was just making doubly (no pun intended) sure.

IntPtr.Size has to be used if the structure is packed with normal packing.  Normally, a simple structure interop would take care of that, but we are not using simply structure interop, here.  If the structure is byte-packed, then you'll want to change the places where it says 'IntPtr.Size' back to just '4'.

That said, provided that we have this in C:

```
typedef struct myStruct_struct
{
    int length;
    double array[1];
}
myStruct;

__declspec(dllexport) myStruct *doSomething(const myStruct *inStruct, double val)
{
    int i = sizeof(double);

    //doSomething ...
    myStruct *outStruct = (myStruct*)GlobalAlloc(0, sizeof(void*) + (8 * 256));
    ZeroMemory(outStruct, sizeof(void*) + (8 * 256));
    outStruct->length = 256;
    outStruct->array[0] = inStruct->array[0] + val;

    return outStruct;
}
```

Then this code in C# would work:

```
  public class Program
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// myStruct is not marshaled, directly.
        /// </summary>
        public struct myStruct
        {

            public int Length;
            public double[] Array;


            private IntPtr _ptr;

            /// <summary>
            /// Custom marshal a structure in from interop (and optionally free the original pointer).
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="ptr"></param>
            /// <param name="freeOrig"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public static myStruct MarshalIn(IntPtr ptr, bool freeOrig = true)
            {
                byte[] by = new byte[4];
                myStruct ns = new myStruct();

                Marshal.Copy(ptr, by, 0, 4);
                ns.Length = BitConverter.ToInt32(by, 0);

                ns.Array = new double[ns.Length];
                by = new byte[ns.Length * 8];

                Marshal.Copy(ptr + IntPtr.Size, by, 0, by.Length);
                Buffer.BlockCopy(by, 0, ns.Array, 0, by.Length);
                if (freeOrig) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

                return ns;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Custom marshal a structure for calling interop.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public IntPtr MarshalOut()
            {
                IntPtr ptr;
                int l = IntPtr.Size + (8 * Array.Length);
                ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(l);

                byte[] by = BitConverter.GetBytes(Length);

                Marshal.Copy(by, 0, ptr, 4);

                by = new byte[Length * 8];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(Array, 0, by, 0, by.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(by, 0, ptr + IntPtr.Size, by.Length);

                _ptr = ptr;
                return ptr;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Free any associated pointer with this structure created with MarshalOut().
            /// </summary>
            public void Free()
            {
                if (_ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(_ptr);
                    _ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
                }
            }
        }

        [DllImport("mylib.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.None, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr doSomething(IntPtr inStruct, double val);


        static void Main()
        {

            // let's do some math.

            myStruct ms = new myStruct(), ms2;
            ms.Array = new double[1];

            ms.Length = 1;
            ms.Array[0] = 424.444;

            ms2 = myStruct.MarshalIn(doSomething(ms.MarshalOut(), 524.444));

            // Free this after the call.
            ms.Free();

        }


    }
```

Comment: This is really the very worst way to solve the underlying problem. Message to question asker: this does what you ask, but you should not do this.

Comment: It's sometimes the only way to solve it ... 

If I had a clearer understanding of the underlying problem, I could have been more useful.  

I do this kind of stuff all day working with the hardware API.  

How, may I ask, is it the 'very' worst way?

Comment: @Nathan: If this is the task, then C# is not the right tool.

Comment: You yourself said that you hate it. The best solution is to allocate the memory in the managed code and let the marshaller do all the work. That requires keeping the dynamically sized arrays out of any structs. Easy enough to do. And it removes the need for all of this code.

Comment: @David: Ah!  But he said in his earlier comments that changing the C code was not an option as it was used in many other places by many other people (because that's the first thing I recommended, as well, in the comments).

Comment: Furthermore, `GlobalAlloc` and `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` are not a matching allocator/deallocator pair.  `FreeHGlobal` is badly named, it doesn't accept an `HGLOBAL` and [it actually calls `LocalFree`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.freehglobal%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: I am not used to working with FreeHGlobal; I call HeapAlloc in all of my code (because that's what MSDN says to do)... However, calling the Free() function doesn't throw any exceptions ...

Comment: Then he's already hosed. Odds on allocation using shared heap very close to zero. Fixing the interface is the solution.

Comment: @ben those are the same these days

Comment: @David: That's what I thought the MSDN said, as well.

Comment: MSDN says: ["It is not safe to free memory allocated with GlobalAlloc using LocalFree."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  @DavidHeffernan

Comment: I'll just stick to HeapAlloc.  :-)

Comment: What he should do is probably write a wrapper in either C or C++/CLI, if that's even an option...

Comment: @Ben I believe that you are right. The 16 difference between LA and GA is long gone. But I believe you are correct about FreeHGlobal. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathan how would HeapAlloc help? You'd have to pinvoke HeapFree. CoTaskMemFree would do the job. But it's a right mess isn't it.

Comment: Yes.  p/Invoking heap alloc and heap free.  That, for all of my own code, is how I choose to allocate memory for p/Invoke.

Comment: It *IS* a mess, that's why I wrote my own library. :-)  It's still a mess, but it becomes more manageable ... I do a lot of p/Invoke for hardware.  I've become very efficient at it.  

... I've also learned, very recently, the CIL is very handy for moving memory around... and I'm currently in the middle of transforming my library to work with that, somewhat.  Some things are even harder in VB...  not impossible, but much harder.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  As I said, I am stuck with these interfaces in C and using C# for calling.  But I can probably write some wrappers.  I will try C++\CLI but know even less than I do about PInvoke.  Has anybody tried using an interface generator like SWIG?  I've had a bit of a play and it seems ok.  Essentially all I'm trying to do is take an unmanaged dll and reuse its code in C#.

Comment: @Nathan I have tried your code and am getting an error saying one or more arguments are invalid.  I've had to amend it slightly to include a second double array in the struct (constant size of 8), I'm guessing the byte positions aren't quite right?

Comment: Actually, no, I ran this code and it worked fine.  However, I was compiling in 64 bit mode.  If you're in 32 bit mode the structure alignment might be different, either 4 bytes, 1 byte, or whatever.  IntPtr.Zero and sizeof(void*) report the same thing, but they might not be the same answer as what I am getting, here.  If your DLL is compiled at 32 bit but your app at 64 bit you might need to play with the alignment by adding or subtracting 4 bytes somewhere.  If the structure is custom aligned, you'd have to determine its alignment or byte packing.  What exact error did you get?

Comment: You might want to try absolute positioning.  Is the C function part of a library provided by a 3rd party?

Comment: The C function is part of a library that we build but for our purposes is probably best thought of as coming from 3rd party as other applications are using it so I don't want to change anything in it unless absolutely necessary.  I am compiling solution in 64 bit, library is 64 bit and c# app is 64 bit.

Comment: is it one IntPtr per array or one IntPtr for all?

Comment: A Single IntPtr will return the starting address of your structure, and from there you should get all of the data. 

If the array inside of the structure is a pointer, then that would be, itself, an IntPtr.

Comment: Okay, well, assuming no structure packing... then your structure should be byte aligned to 8 byte intervals.  Since all doubles are 8 bytes ... then the length should be 8 bytes.

What you need to do is take a look at the byte-by-byte result, copy the IntPtr returned into a byte array, and deduce for yourself where the array begins, then use the FieldOffset(x) attribute on each field along with the StructLayout(LayoutKind.Absolute) attribute on the structure to get the correct alignment.

Comment: If you have access to the C code, I suggest you write a wrapper function that consumes this C code, in C, and produces a result you can easily port to .NET...

Comment: I have gotten a bit further.  I have edited the code above to show the changes. I am now marshaling the array to an intPtr in the struct, then marshaling the struct to an intPtr and calling the c function with that.  It kind of works.  Although sometimes I am getting AccessViolationExceptions when calling MarshalArray, and then if it does get past that it always gets the same exception when  calling UnMarshalArray at the point of copying from the ArrayPtr.

Comment: That is incorrect.  Your elements are still being passed in the same memory stream as the structure.  The first element of the array is NOT a pointer and should not be treated as such.  

You should try removing the double[8] that you have declared, and in your StructLayout specify StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1) and see if that helps.

Comment: In all honesty, if you can change the code like that, you should choose another way to get to C#.  Write a wrapper function that lets C# allocate the memory for the buffer, on its own, and return it in the argument list as a ref IntPtr

Comment: Unfortunately I can't remove the double[8].  That is the struct I have to work with, the original one was just a little tester until I realized this was fairly non-trivial and the order and number and type of things in struct mattered.  I will try c++\cli now, cheers for all the help

Comment: You're going to run into the same issue.  it's just a different language... but the managed portion compiles to the same managed assemblies.  The memory still needs to be marshaled.